# Replacing array with a class that acts like array but provides type specific functions?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a class like this:

```
export class IManor {
    tenants: ITenant[];
```

But I have some aggregate querying funtionality I'd like off of tenants as well and would like to replace it with a class.  I know I can attend Array for this but want to be able to access the interface of contents for the aggregate functions, for something like:

```
class Tenants extends Array<ITenant> {

  totalAcres(): number {
    let total = 0;
    for (const tenant in this) {
      total += tenant.acres;
      }
      return total;
  }
}
```

but the function doesn't appear to be aware of it's interface.  My googling turns up generic array extensions only (and the problems with those).

The goal is to be able to to the normal 'let tenant of manor.tenants' while also doing things like manor.tenants.totalAcres();

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's much of a benefit to extending array functionality except to be clever... Why not just use `let tenant of manor.getTenants()` or something like that? You could even implement a getter to return the internal array (or a copy)

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance of you class from `Array<ITenant>` doesn't affect your previous definition in any way. If you want you methods to be available in `IManor` class you have to define `tenants` member as `Tenants`. In this case you cannot use array syntax for constructing this entity but `new Tenants()` instead, but all other array method(like `filter`, `map`, etc) will be available as well as your methods like `totalAcres`.
So `IManor` definition will look like:

```
export class IManor {
    tenants: Tenants = new Tenants();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes this is what I'm looking to do.  I'd like to be able to for ... of.. on manor.tenants as well as all the other array stuff like push/pop.

My problem is trying to setup the Tenants class, I don't know how it should be setup so that internally I'm able to access the type, like in the function example above.  Perhaps I need to always cast it 'as ITenant'?

Comment: @Streamweaver Your code does it. I only replace for..in with for..of cycles. There is example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ITenant%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20acres%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Tenants%20extends%20Array%3CITenant%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20totalAcres()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20total%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20tenant%20of%20this)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20total%20%2B%3D%20tenant.acres%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20total%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A

Comment: Well heck.  My IDE kept telling me it didn't work, I should have actually run the code instead of assuming it knew what it was doing.

Comment: Okay, this is still a problem.  Declaring a new Tenants array in the IManor constructor or as above, whenever I try to use a function on the tenants array (i.e. in this example manor.tenants.totalAcres()) I get an error saying totalAcres isn't a function, if I try to get the type of tenants it says undefined.